# Can I remove the Child class' constructor when using Lombok's @SuperBuild annotation

Tags: java, intellij-idea, lombok, intellij-lombok-plugin

I'm new to using Lombok annotations. My goal is to minimize any code boilerplate through the use of Lombok annotations

I have the ff. Child class which I annotated with Lombok's `@SuperBuilder`

```
@Service
@SuperBuilder
public class Child extends Parent{ //class doesn't contain matching constructor for autowiring (error message)
    private final ChildFieldA a;
    private final ChildFieldB b;
    private final ChildFieldC c;
    
    public Child(ParentField d, ParentField e, ChildField a, ChildField b, ChildField c){
        super(d,e); //Expected 1 arguments but found 3 (error message)
        this.a = a;
        this.b = b;
        this.c = c;
    }
}
```

And the abstract parent class,

```
@SuperBuilder
public abstract class Parent{
    private final ParentField d;
    private final ParentField e;
}
```

Notice that with the current definitions of the 2 classes, there are 2 error messages on the Child class.
If I remove the entire **Child** class's **constructor** altogether, can the `@SuperBuilder` annotation on the Child class guarantee that the initialization of the final fields still happen?
In other words, can I totally just remove the **Child** class's **constructor** and keep the `@SuperBuilder` annotations on both **Child** and **Parent** class?

I specifically want to use `@SuperBuilder`. I read somewhere that I can't mix `@Builder` with `@SuperBuilder` in a class.

I'd appreciate any suggestions or explanation.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on your use case. If you solely use `@SuperBuilder` to programmatically create instances of your class, it's reasonable to remove all other constructors.

However, `@Service` indicates you are using Spring. Spring cannot use builders to perform autowiring. It can only use constructor- or setter-based injection.
So you'll need either a constructor with all required beans, or a no-args constructor and setters for them.